# What is the game the kids of Lenny are playing in the TV in the movie Grown Ups?

Tags: grown-ups

In [Grown ups](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375670/) what is the game the kids of Lenny are playing on the TV?

[image: The game in the TV]

Comment: if that game was real i have to amit it would be beast i mean look at the game awsome graphics great weapons just a master peice my favorite is grammy overborad +200 lol
other then looks like a good game not a crappy one

Comment: This is a real game, or there is a real game like this, I remember play it when I was younger and I'm trying to figure out what the name is, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently saw this film, and wondered the same thing.  However, after seeing more of the game as it was played, I came to the conclusion that it was a fake game, made specifically for the movie.

I expect making a few basic snippets of a game is cheaper than paying for the rights to use a real game.

Comment: And in the end I guess this *"game"* was specifically made to satirize the ridiculously cruel video games those stupid kids are playing (man, they're killing people sitting at the swimming pool).

Comment: Adam Sandler actually has similar fictional games in a few different movies he's been in or that his production company has made. Reign Over Me, Momma's Boy and Funny People are 3 that I know of that have fake video games.

Comment: Reign Over Me has fake video games?  The main video game I recall from that movie is *Shadow of the Colossus*, which is a real game.